# How to implement a basic Datalog interpreter?

Tags: datalog

I am looking for a good tutorial on how to implement a basic Datalog interpreter for learning purposes. I have found a lot of papers which discuss how to make them faster or add some features but none that describes how to implement a basic one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sample implimentation, Java source code included:

http://abcdatalog.seas.harvard.edu/

The developers explicitly cite facilitation of research and pedagogy among their objectives.

There are also many links to open source projects here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog#Systems_implementing_Datalog

Best of luck!